# Error in forked process displayed due to dependsonmethod when testng.xml is run with maven-surefire

Tags: testng, maven-surefire-plugin, testng.xml

I am getting "Error in Forked Process" with cause saying that one of the @test is depending on a method and the Method is not annotated with @test.

My testng.xml does not have the mentioned @test class at all and I am not sure why this @test is being picked up in first place.

My POM.XML

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        
                        <skip>false</skip>
                        <forkCount>2</forkCount>
                        <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
                        <maven.test.failure.ignore>false</maven.test.failure.ignore>
                        <rerunFailingTestsCount>2</rerunFailingTestsCount>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Junit & testNG versions :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
```

TestnG :

```
<suite name="StoresCentral_TestSuite_Param" configfailurepolicy="continue" verbose="10" 
threadcount="1" parallel="none"><test name="POC_tests_0"><classes><class 
name="au.wow.ngbomain.tests.PracticeArtLookupTest"></class></classes></test></suite>
```

Error :

[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Automation\ForkErrorCheck\s\Test\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR]
[ERROR] au.wow.ngbomain.tests.AdjustmentLogReportTests.pageValidation() is depending on method public void au.wow.ngbomain.tests.Sample.check() throws java.lang.Exception, which is not annotated with @Test or not included.
[ERROR] org.testng.TestNGException: